# The List View show empty when the data load on onAppear of the view in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, observable, swiftui-list, onappear

**when I load data and set to @Published on onAppear of view in swiftUI, the List view had been rerender and loop each data but the list view is show empty**

**this is my struct for @Published**

```
struct AddNewSongState {
    var arrayMP3File: [MP3File] = []
    var selectedCount: Int = 0
    var isLoaded: Bool = false
}
```

**
and this is my ObservableObject class**

```
final class AddNewSongsHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var state: AddNewSongState
    
    let playlist: Playlist?
    init(state: AddNewSongState = .init(), playlist: Playlist?) {
        self.state = state
        self.playlist = playlist
    }

    func loadListSong() {
        state.arrayMP3File = DocumentFileManager.shared.loadMP3File()
    }
........
}
```

**I declare on my class**

```
struct AddNewSongsView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var handler: AddNewSongsHandler
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            .......
               List {
                    ForEach(handler.state.arrayMP3File.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        Button {
                            handler.send(intent: .toggleSelectedAt(index: index))
                            
                        } label: {
                            SongItemView()
                            .......
                    }
                }
                .modifier(ListBackgroundModifier())
                .cornerRadius(8, corners: .allCorners)
        } // VStack
        .background(Color.black)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .onAppear {
            handler.send(intent: .loadListSong)
        }
    }
}
```

**
The view had been rerender with the data correctly but the List view dont show any SongItemView()

but when i load the list song on the init AddNewSongsHandler the List view is showing correctly **

Comment: Try `.task` instead of `.onAppear`/`ObservableObject` and remove indices from the ForEach and make MP3File `Identifiable`.

Comment: tks for your answer, this error happend when i don't create a instance of AddNewSongsHandler, i just create new instance in the parameter when create the AddNewSongsView(), when i try to create a @StateObject when init the parent view  and pass it to AddNewSongsView(), the error have gone, more detail is, MP3File struct is Identifiable already

Comment: i will update the answer on the tomorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my error, in my code when passing the handler to AddNewSongsView I create an handler and passing it withthout any variable to save that instance

```
AddNewSongsView(viewModel: AddNewSongsViewModel(...))
```

and when I try create an instance to hold the AddNewSongsViewModel the bug is Gone . In the parent view of AddNewSongsView:

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: PlaylistViewModel
@StateObject var addNewsSongVM: AddNewSongsViewModel
init(viewModel: PlaylistViewModel) {
     self.viewModel = viewModel
     self._addNewsSongVM = StateObject(wrappedValue: AddNewSongsViewModel(playlist: viewModel.state.playlist))
    }
```

and then you just need to pass to the AddNewSongsView

Im still confuse how dose it work? if anyone know please add comment or answer in this question, thank you so much